# SQL Server query INNER JOIN - missing entries

Tags: sql-server, join

FYI - this query runs from excel. i have prompt fields to set date range.

here is the original working query i got from someone:

```
SELECT 
   SalesInvoiceItems.FreeTextItem, SalesInvoiceItems.Product,   
   SalesInvoiceItems.ItemDescription, SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity, 
   SalesInvoiceItems.ItemValue, Customers.CustomerId, Customers.CustomerName, 
   SalesInvoices.SalesInvoiceId, SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate, Countries.CountryId, 
   SalesInvoiceItems.ItemType
FROM 
   Winman.dbo.Countries Countries, Winman.dbo.Customers Customers, 
   Winman.dbo.Products Products, Winman.dbo.SalesInvoiceItems SalesInvoiceItems, 
   Winman.dbo.SalesInvoices SalesInvoices
WHERE 
    Customers.Customer = SalesInvoices.Customer 
    AND SalesInvoiceItems.SalesInvoice = SalesInvoices.SalesInvoice 
    AND Customers.Country = Countries.Country 
    AND ((SalesInvoices.SystemType='F') 
    AND (SalesInvoiceItems.ItemType<>'T') 
    AND (SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate>=? And SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate<=?) 
    AND (SalesInvoiceItems.ItemValue<>$0))
ORDER BY 
    SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity DESC
```

Important bit here is `ItemType` (it can only be T, wich is excluded, P - for products and N - for free text items)

I needed to add table `Products`, to retrieve `ProductID`. Obviously adding below code in `WHERE` clause:

```
AND Products.Product = SalesInvoiceItems.Product
```

will fail to bring up any free text item, as the aren't products.

So I rewrote query with JOINs hoping that will solve my problem (bringing up both P and N type of entries):

```
SELECT 
    Products.ProductId, 
    SalesInvoiceItems.FreeTextItem, 
    SalesInvoiceItems.Product, 
    SalesInvoiceItems.ItemDescription, 
    SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity, 
    SalesInvoiceItems.ItemValue, 
    Customers.CustomerId, 
    Customers.CustomerName, 
    SalesInvoices.SalesInvoiceId, 
    SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate, 
    Countries.CountryId, 
    SalesInvoiceItems.ItemType
FROM 
    Winman.dbo.SalesInvoiceItems AS SalesInvoiceItems 
INNER JOIN 
    Winman.dbo.Products AS Products ON Products.Product = SalesInvoiceItems.Product  
INNER JOIN 
    Winman.dbo.SalesInvoices AS SalesInvoices ON SalesInvoices.SalesInvoice= SalesInvoiceItems.SalesInvoice
INNER JOIN 
    Winman.dbo.Customers AS Customers ON Customers.Customer = SalesInvoices.Customer 
INNER JOIN 
    Winman.dbo.Countries AS Countries ON  Countries.Country = Customers.Country 
WHERE 
    ((SalesInvoices.SystemType='F') 
     AND (SalesInvoiceItems.ItemType<>'T') 
     AND (SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate >= ? And SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate <= ?) 
     AND (SalesInvoiceItems.ItemValue <> $0)
    )
ORDER BY 
    SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity DESC
```

but this still acts as AND - which ignores free text items! I'm obviously missing something.. how can I bring both products and free text items, despite that free text items don't have `ProductID` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your old query is using old style `JOIN` syntax. It is a good thing to completely abandon this implicit (inner) joining in favor of explicit joining.

When using explicit joins, you now have **a choice** between `INNER` and `OUTER` joins ([ref. MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx)).

> Inner joins return rows only when there is at least one row from both
>   tables that matches the join condition. Inner joins eliminate the rows
>   that do not match with a row from the other table. **Outer joins,
>   however, return all rows from at least one of the tables or views**
>   mentioned in the FROM clause, as long as those rows meet any WHERE or
>   HAVING search conditions.

So in response to your question, change your `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s

Comment: yes of course!!! i didn't even think of that! although i had to battle with microsoft query to make it accept it...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly but try changing:

```
INNER JOIN Winman.dbo.Products AS Products ON ...
```

to:

```
LEFT JOIN Winman.dbo.Products AS Products ON ...
```